# When I log in to a Windows member machine, how does it authenticate me?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, kerberos

When I log in to a Windows member server in an Windows AD domain, does it use LDAP or Kerberos to authenticate me?

I have always been under the impression that this was done with LDAP, but wondering if it is actually Kerberos. Is it by default, encrypted traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD uses both Kerberos and LDAP.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2005.01.activedirectory.aspx

> I am going to boil this down simplistically, since it
>   seems you need to start from the very beginning.  Kerberos is the
>   default authentication (and authorization) protocol used by Active
>   Directory, though it is classically thought of as an authentication
>   protocol only.  Kerberos is platform-independent and was invented at
>   MIT, and Microsoft later adopted it beginning Windows 2000 Active
>   Directory to provide you single sign-on access (which means you only
>   enter your password one time when you first logon) to subsequent
>   network resources on your network and not challenge you again for a
>   username and password.  Kerberos is involved in nearly everything,
>   from the moment you first logon to access your computer, to accessing
>   the SYSVOL share on Domain Controllers, by handing out what are known
>   as tickets, which are encrypted.  Kerberos largely replaced NTLM, an
>   older and Microsoft’s original (with Windows NT) authentication
>   protocol.  LDAP is also an authentication and authorization protocol,
>   and also methodology of organizing objects such as users, computers,
>   and organizational units within a directory, such as Active Directory.
>   It is basically the list view of what you see when you open up the
>   Active Directory Users and Computers console.  Kerberos is more secure
>   than LDAP, and they are often used together.  For example, when you
>   open up the Active Directory Users and Computers console, your
>   computer first obtains a ticket to access your Domain Controller and
>   then uses LDAP to actually use the console itself when working with
>   objects such as users or OUs.  Kerberos and LDAP allow you to run a
>   heterogeneous network of Windows, Linux, UNIX and even Apple Mac
>   clients on a Microsoft Active Directory network.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb6b05cc-3162-456d-a987-d113821fbdd6/difference-between-kerberos-and-ldap-in-active-directory?forum=winserverDS

And yes, it is encrypted OOB.

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos is used for **authentication**,
LDAP for **authorization**

Kerberos only stores logins & passwords (and a bunch of options stating if kerberos tickets are forwardable etc.), and that's about it.

once kerberos authenticated you, your permissions (group membership etc.) are managed within the LDAP directory.